# Make a div take the entire available height space

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

I am working on css grid layout page, where i want the content `div` to fill the remaining space of the screen after the header, but ended up having blank space at the bottom of the page.
Any ideas how to increase the height or stretch the div to fill the entire space as shown in this the image?
[Web page made by adobe illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plo2M.jpg)

The two sections to the left must have the same height, i think this should do:

```css
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><h2>Travelto</h2></div>
        <div class="search-bar"></div>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">Blog</a>
            <a href="">Services</a>
            <div id="profile-picture"></div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper-grid">
        <section class="about">
           <h1>Explore The World With Us</h1>
            <p>Discover breathtaking destnations.                
                Start your adventure today!
            </p>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <article>
                <h2>Going somewhere?</h2>
                <p>Are you in the midst of planning a trip and feeling overwhelmed by the multitude of destinations, offers, and prices available?</p>
                   </article>
            <article>
                <h2>We got you covered.</h2>
                <p>We're here to assist you in discovering the finest hotels at the most competitive prices, offering you a selection of hundreds of options to choose from.</p>
            </article>
            <button>More info</button>
        </aside>
        <section class="call-to-action">
            <h3>Unforgettable journeys are waiting for you.</h3>
            <button>Book now</button>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient( 30deg,#5ba591 , #050a26 );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
header {  
    grid-column: span 3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
header nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 header nav #profile-picture {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 30px;
 }
.wrapper-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 30px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    height: calc(100vh - 75px);
}

.about {
    grid-column: span 2;
    display: grid;
    gap: 30px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: end;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 6px; 
    background-color:  rgba(5,10,38,0.3); 
}
.about h1 {
     font-size: 3rem;
}
.about p {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
}
aside {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: span 2;
    display: grid;
    gap: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 6px; 
    background-color: rgba(14,155,134,0.2);   
}
aside article p {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
aside button {
    justify-self: center;
    background: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px; 
}
.call-to-action {
    grid-column: span 2;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px;
    border: #5ba591 1px solid;
    border-radius: 6px; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
}
.call-to-action button {
    justify-self: center;
    background: #ffc500;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px; 
}
```

Comment: I put your code into a codepent.io seems fine to me. I guess the "error" might be in the rest of your code.

Comment: @mokorana actually it's not fine, when you put it in codepen and view it in the editor, change the view by putting the source code to the side, you will clearly see the white space at the bottom.
and there is no rest of the code, that's all there is.